# Does a fluid get colder when it does work?

Tags: thermodynamics

Imagine I have water at 80 degrees, in an environment in which everything else is also 80 degrees. Using gravity I make the water flow over a turbine (also 80 degrees) and the turbine does some work. Will the water be colder when it comes off the turbine? The work is done by gravity, not by the thermal energy of the water so how much thermal energy would be lost and how would it be lost? It can't radiate to the environment or the turbine because by hypothesis everything is in thermal equilibrium.

Answer (score 3):

You say in your question:

> The work is done by gravity, not by the thermal energy of the water

and this is the key point. In the many, many problems physics students are given involving expanding gases the work comes from the kinetic energy of the gas molecules, i.e. the internal energy of the gas. And since the internal energy of the gas is decreased the gas gets colder as it expands.

However in this case the energy is coming from the change in the potential energy of the water. If the turbine was 100% efficient all that potential energy would go into work and the water would stay at 80ºC. In the real world some energy is lost due to viscous forces in the water, so some of the potential energy change goes into work and the rest into heating up the water. The water will exit the turbine hotter than 80ºC not colder.

Answer (score 0):

Turbine is a device with steady flow process and it has one inlet and one exit. [First law of thermodynamics for a steady flow process](https://wiki.ucl.ac.uk/display/MechEngThermodyn/First+law+applied+to+flow+processes) with one inlet and one exit is as below
$$q-w=(h_e-h_i)+\frac 12\left(V_e^2-V_i^2\right)+g(z_e-z_i)$$
Potential energy change is negligible for this device ($z_e-z_i$ is small). If the turbine is adiabatic, then we will have:
$$-w=(h_e-h_i)+\frac 12\left(V_e^2-V_i^2\right)$$
And if specific heat capacity of the water is constant, then
$$h_e-h_i=C_p(T_e-T_i)=-w-\frac 12\left(V_e^2-V_i^2\right)$$
Now, for comparing $T_i$ with $T_e$ you need to measure work done by water and its kinetic energy change.

If $-w-\frac 12\left(V_e^2-V_i^2\right)\lt 0$ then $T_e\lt T_i$

If $-w-\frac 12\left(V_e^2-V_i^2\right)\gt 0$ then $T_e\gt T_i$

And if $-w-\frac 12\left(V_e^2-V_i^2\right)=0$ then $T_e=T_i$